# How do I implement the "percent uptime" metric for my website?

Tags: heroku, amazon-ec2, web

How do I implement a "percent uptime" metric that potential customers browsing my website can look at? The site is hosted on Heroku.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is pretty broad but consider using a third party application to monitor your traffic and statistics.

I would recommend something like [New Relic](https://addons.heroku.com/newrelic)

Comment: I have yet to investigate this answer.